# XmlRpcException: No Such Handler: Default.queryPT while executing XQuery

Tags: java, xquery, xml-rpc, exist-db

I want to launch an XQuery to an exist database. Code seems simple enough

```
String driver = "org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl";
Database database = (Database) Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
DatabaseManager.registerDatabase(database);
Collection col = DatabaseManager.getCollection(mydburi, login, pass);
XQueryService service = (XQueryService) collection.getService("XQueryService", "3.0");
String query="xquery version \"1.0\";let $message := 'Hello World!'return <results><message>{$message}</message></results>";
ResourceSet result = service.query(query);`
```

Problem is that that last line throws an exception such as

> org.xmldb.api.base.XMLDBException: No such handler: Default.queryPT
>       at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteXPathQueryService.query(RemoteXPathQueryService.java:115)
>       at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteXPathQueryService.query(RemoteXPathQueryService.java:72)
>       at server.DatabaseManagerExist.doQuery(DatabaseManagerExist.java:230)
>       at server.DatabaseManagerExist.main(DatabaseManagerExist.java:327)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: No such handler: Default.queryPT
>       at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)
>       at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
>       at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
>       at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
>       at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
>       at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
>       at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
>       at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
>       at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteXPathQueryService.query(RemoteXPathQueryService.java:100)
>       ... 3 more

I haven't been able to find any information about this exception or the Default.queryPT it references, and I have no idea what it could be causing it.

The collection exists and I can access the given collection to perform other operations like storing or reading resources. I can copy the query in Exide and it works just fine. I have also tried the most basic Hello World query with same results. I've also using XQueryService 1.0 without any luck.

I'm using exist-db v4.0.0 library to connect to the database.

Any idea of what is the handler Default.queryPT and how/where do I change it?

Comment: I am no architect of the exist-db, so I believe for all like me it would be very helpful if you provide some more code: java, xQuery and also a stacktrace from exist-db logs. To get an answer, it would be best if the issue can be reproducible.

Comment: The only other line that is needed to reproduce the error is obtaining the collection, I'll add the full stacktrace and complete the example

Comment: Currently, I have installed exist-db v3.6.0 on my machine, and I am using library with the same version. With my setup I cannot reproduce the exception. Is there any chance that you have installed the database of different version than the library you are using?

Comment: Thanks @milijan seems like this was the problem, I was using a 4.0.0 library over a 3.X database. I was assuming there was no problem with the database as I was able to connect and access it for all operations except querying. If you want propose this as a solution an I'll accept it.

Comment: @milijan Indeed, the XML-RPC API was changed between eXist-db 3.6.0 and eXist-db 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlRpcException` is a result of changed XML-RPC API in eXist-db 4.0.0 (as confirmed by @adamretter from [eXist](http://exist-db.org/) development team) and the fact that you are using 4.0.0 library over some older database. I believe that best practice is to always use a database and a library of the same version, and that way avoid problems caused by their incoherence such as possible changes in the API.